# Why doesn't routines support the ability to turn on/off thermostats?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

If I want a set of thermostats to turn on in the morning and turn off in the afternoon, I was hoping to do that via a routine. However, in the manage routines page for adjusting thermostat, you can only change the set temperature. How would I go about turning on/off thermostats using a routine? Would I need to add the OnOff trait just to get this to show up?

Alternatively, I could use the add action part of routine and make it do "Turn on Ben's thermostat". That could work but what if I have like 5 thermostats, that doesn't seem the way to go. Is there a way to control multiple thermostats in one command? For eg. turn on bens thermostat, kates thermostat and bedroom thermostat.

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't an option in the menu that you would want, you can always manually add commands such as controlling your devices.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes you are correct. But as I said, if I have 10 thermostats then it makes no sense to do it like that. That would mean. I would need to add 10 custom commands. Multiplied by the number of routines I need to do ( minimum 2, one for turning on and one for turning off) then your method isn't practical, especially for customers who want to use our skill. Unless I can do all this in one custom commands, which I've tried experimenting but can't achieve. How would I go about this? Alexa for example has the ability to do routines but you can control every aspect of a thermostat, not just temperature.

Comment: This is how you would do ti.